# WinForms with CEFSharp lose background and begin transparent

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

I use WinForms with CEFSharp 41.0.1 and have next problem: the background of the application (google.com is opened) **lose background** and begin transparent on the Windows 7 from the beginning till the end and provide same behavior when switching system users on the Windows 8 until focusing the app.

Furthermore, for Windows 8 the application sometimes **can not take focus in** after it, you are trying to focus in input in google but go through the application to the background app. *This is very big trouble for our app.*

I cannot show Windows 7 case now, so I show the behavior for Windows 8 with changing system users after Ctrl + Alt + Delete -> Switch User

1. Screenshots for Windows 8 (before switching users):
   [image]
2. Screenshots for Windows 8 (after switching system users):
   [image]
   For that case is impossible to take a screenshot because whenever you focus in application, it re-renders and looks correctly.

I use next code for creating browser object and adding to the form:

```
_browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("google.com")
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,              
            MenuHandler = new CustomMenuHandler(),
            BrowserSettings = new BrowserSettings()
            {
                ApplicationCacheDisabled = false,
                FileAccessFromFileUrlsAllowed = true,
                JavascriptDisabled = false,
                LocalStorageDisabled = false,
                WebSecurityDisabled = true,
                JavaScriptOpenWindowsDisabled = false,
                JavascriptDomPasteDisabled = false,
            }
        };
        RegisterWrappers();
        Controls.Add(_browser);
```

and next code for the initialization:

```
Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings()
            {
                CachePath = "cache"
               });

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Application.Run(new Context(new Form1()));
```

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Does the problem reproduce using the latest release version? (`43.0.1`). You can use the `MinimalExample` project to test it out https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: @amaitland, the problem have reproduced with latest release version, but  MinimalExample with WinForms works correctly. I dont see the big differences between my project and MinimalExample

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to **delete TransparencyKey property from the WinForms**. In our project it was set to White and white background content in browser becomes transparent in Windows 7 but for Windows 8 it is not work correctly so it was difficult to detect problem.